# Add column with rolling calculation group by

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table like this:

| current_date | user_id | mode_name | mode_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | music | 10 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 | music | 40 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | music | 10 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | music | 20 |
| 2021-10-05 | 2 | tv | 40 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | tv | 40 |
| 2021-10-12 | 2 | game | 20 |

And I want to add two columns:

1. Column with favourite `mode_name`, according cumulate sum of `mode_time` column for every `user_id`
2. Column with cumulate sum of `mode_time` column from favourite `mode_name` for every `user_id`

The desired table should look like this:

| current_date | user_id | mode_name | mode_time | favourite_mode | favourite_mode_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | game | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | game | 10 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | tv | 30 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | music | 10 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 | music | 40 | music | 50 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | music | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | game | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | game | 10 | music | 30 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | music | 20 | music | 30 |
| 2021-10-05 | 2 | tv | 40 | tv | 40 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | tv | 40 | tv | 80 |
| 2021-10-12 | 2 | game | 20 | tv | 80 |

Table can be found here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e05302a2cfd81a2a55de811e294f513e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` with partition by user and mode to calculate rolling sum for mode and then use `max` and `max_by` to get corresponding values in outer select:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (date, user_id, mode_name, mode_time) AS (
    values ('2021-10-01', 1, 'game', 10),
        ('2021-10-02', 1, 'game', 10),
        ('2021-10-02', 1, 'tv', 30),
        ('2021-10-09', 1, 'music', 10),
        ('2021-10-15', 1, 'music', 40),
        ('2021-10-01', 2, 'game', 10),
        ('2021-10-01', 2, 'music', 10),
        ('2021-10-04', 2, 'game', 10),
        ('2021-10-04', 2, 'music', 20),
        ('2021-10-05', 2, 'tv', 40),
        ('2021-10-11', 2, 'tv', 40),
        ('2021-10-12', 2, 'game', 20)
) 

--query
SELECT date, user_id, mode_name, mode_time,
    max_by(mode_name, mode_time_rolling_time) OVER (
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY date
    ) AS favourite_mode,
    max(mode_time_rolling_time) OVER (
        PARTITION BY user_id
        ORDER BY date
    ) AS favourite_mode_time
FROM(
        SELECT *,
            sum(mode_time) OVER (
                PARTITION BY user_id,
                mode_name
                ORDER BY date
            ) AS mode_time_rolling_time
        FROM dataset
    )
ORDER BY user_id, date
```

Output:

| date | user_id | mode_name | mode_time | favourite_mode | favourite_mode_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | game | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | game | 10 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | tv | 30 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | music | 10 | tv | 30 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 | music | 40 | music | 50 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | game | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 | music | 10 | game | 10 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | music | 20 | music | 30 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | game | 10 | music | 30 |
| 2021-10-05 | 2 | tv | 40 | tv | 40 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | tv | 40 | tv | 80 |
| 2021-10-12 | 2 | game | 20 | tv | 80 |

Comment: Great! Works as expected) Many thanks